# Change page layout in the middle of report (SSRS)

Tags: layout, reporting-services, report

Hei,

I have a main report with Portrait layout, but the main report contains subreports and some of subreports needs to be in Landscape layout.

Is it possible to change main report layout so that it shows some subreports as lanscape and some in portrait?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't think this is possible, at least not in SSRS 2008.

From the **subreports section** at the end of this [Rendering Report Items MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677570%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Subreports can grow to the size of the body defined in the .rdl file that defines the subreport. For example, if the RDL for the subreport states that the subreport body is 5 inches wide, then the subreport will be 5 inches wide within the parent report.

In addition it mentions that the page header and footer from subreports are omitted. All this indicates that the Page Size from a report is not used at all if it's rendered as a subreport. The parent's Page Size is used in the entire report, thus enforcing a single layout (page size) on the entire report.